# Binding Visibility of a ComboBox to Multiple Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Suppose I have a Window named MainWindow.xaml and a Page named Page.xaml.

**On MainWindow.xaml :**

I have a `Menu` and a `Frame`. In this Frame Page.xaml is displayed.

`DataContext` of `MainWindow.xaml` is bound to `MainWindowViewModel`.

I have a property called `SelectedMenuItem` of type `int` on `MainWindowViewModel`.

So, Menu's SelectedItem is bound to `SelectedMenuItem`.

**On Page.xaml :**

I have 2 `ComboBoxes` named `Combo1` and `Combo2`.

Now I want to bind `Visibility` of `Combo2` to somthing.

**The required Behavior :**

Combo2 should be visible when `Combo1's first item is selected && SelectedMenuItem = 1`.

So, How should I bind Combo2's Visibility?

**Update :**

According to your answer, I have tried to implement IMultiValueConverter like below code:

EffectsVisibilityConverter.cs

```
public class EffectsVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(values[0] == null || values[1] == null))
        {
            if (((int)values[0] == 1) && ((int)values[1] == 1))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Page.xaml :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Effects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"  
          DisplayMemberPath="Effect" SelectedValue="{Binding EffectID}" SelectedValuePath="EffectID">
    <ComboBox.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource effectsVisibilityConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedParent" >
                <Binding.Source>
                    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedGroupID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.Visibility>
</ComboBox>
```

But problem is that, the value of values[0] in Converter always remains 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MultiBinding and Converter  :instead of menuitem I've used Checkbox's `IsChecked`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox x:Name="cbox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="3"   MinHeight="20">
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="first" />
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="second"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="third"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="fourth"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="3"   MinHeight="20" >
            <ComboBox.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="cbox1"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="chkbox"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ComboBox.Visibility>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="1" />
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="2"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="3"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="4"/>
            </ComboBox>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkbox" Content="Isselected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((values[0] is ComboBoxItem) && (values[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "first" && (bool)values[1])

            return Visibility.Visible;
        else return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

update//

```
<ComboBox.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="cbox1"/>
        <Binding  Path="IsChecked">
            <Binding.RelativeSource >
                <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type Window}" />
            </Binding.RelativeSource>

        </Binding>
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.Visibility>
```

Comment: I have got some problems. Please see Update in question.

Comment: Is your ViewModel Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged Interface ?

Comment: Yes, my ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

Comment: please try something like the update,and let me know if it works

Comment: I have tried Update mentioned in your answer. But that doesn't work. I mean I get `values[0] = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` after trying RelativeSource.

Comment: Please post your problem as simplified sample,that reproduces issue

Comment: I have got it. In my App.xaml I declared a resource as follows <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel" /> and then I used it as source for ComboBox's Multibinding's Binding. And Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and bind e.g. SelectedMenuItem and Combo1.SelectedIndex to the converter to determine the visibility of Combo2.

I would prefere this way instead of creating new viewmodel properties because it's pure ui logic and has nothing to do with the viewmodels logic.

//Edit

Why you don't use the binding like Kuna wrote?

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
    <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="cbox1"/>
    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="chkbox"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Just use SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem and everything's fine.

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding my question. SelectedItem works fine. But for SelectedMenuItem I get the problem. SelectedMenuItem is in MainWindowViewModel but my Page's DataSource is PageViewModel.

Comment: And the ComboxBox is at the view which DataContext is MainWindowViewModel? Does the MainWindowViewModel know the PageViewModel? maybe it would be easier to know more about the viewmodels.

Comment: Yes and No, I mean MainWindowViewModel and PageViewModel are both public as well as they are under same namespace. So I think they know each other. But I have not written any code such that one refers the other. I am a bit confused by looking at your question in above comment.

Comment: Maybe we aren't talking about the same thing. It would be interesting to know your view and viewmodel construct. For me it seems you want to bind to a property which is in a viewmodel you can't access from your view.

Comment: My View is Page.xaml. Its dataContext is bound to PageViewModel. The ComboBox that we are trying to bind resides in Page.xaml. Now I have a Property called SelectedMenuItem in a viewModel called MainWindowViewModel. I want to bind the above mentioned ComboBox's Visibility Property to SelectedMenuItem. Is it OK? or do you want more information?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. So you want to bind to a property which isn't part of your actual datacontext. That's not possible. At least I don't know how it could be possible.

Comment: I have got it. In my App.xaml I declared a resource as follows `<vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel" />` and then I used it as source for ComboBox's Multibinding's Binding.

Comment: Your welcome. Maybe I got give you at least an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another property to your viewmodel and do the logic in there.